# Strange behavior using COS() and SIN() in Fortran 77

Tags: fortran

I'm getting some strange behavior using COS() and SIN() libraries in Fortran 77. It picks what number to perform it's operation on like here :

```
DATA V , THETA , PI / 100 , 45 , 3.1416 /

THETA = THETA * PI/ 180.0
PRINT *, "THETA = " , THETA

VX = V * COS ( THETA )
VY = V * SIN ( THETA )

PRINT *, VX , VY 
END
```

when i check it, i find that

> COS(THETA) = COS(45)

not

> COS(0.7853)

and the same goes to SIN() too. So why does this happen ?

This is my output :

> THETA = 0.785400
>
> ```
>   70.7105    70.7108
> ```

Comment: Q: You're saying that when you print theta, you're seeing 0.7845 as expected.  But when you print cos(theta), you're getting the cosine of 45.0 (instead of the cosine of 0.7845).  Correct?  You;re calling "COS()" (which should take radians), but you're getting "COSD()" which takes degrees).  Is this the problem?  Q: What FORTRAN compiler are you using?  What platform are you running on?

Comment: Do you have implicit or explicit typing in the _actual code_?

Comment: @paulsm4 I'm using Fortran 77. And Windows 7

Comment: @PaulTomblin I've edited the question with the output ;)

Comment: @talonmies I've used implicit typing.

Comment: Those are the correct results.  You're taking the cos of 45 degrees (converted to radians) and multiplying it by 100, and the cos of 45 degrees (or pi/4 radians) is 0.7071067, and so the expected value to print out is 70.7106

Comment: @PaulTomblin But why does it take 45. Why not the actual THETA value (0.785400) ?? Sorry i'm kinda beginner here

Comment: You're calling SIN, which expects a value in radians, not in degrees.  That's why you converted your THETA value of 45 DEGREES into 0.785400 RADIANS.

Comment: @Rafael - .7854300 radians == 45 degrees.  The FORTRAN sin() and cos() functions take radians, not degrees.  You're correctly converting degrees to radians (pi / 180.0).  I thought you *knew* all that, and assumed you were somehow getting the *wrong* answer.  Maybe not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the correct results. You're taking the cos of 45 degrees (converted to radians) and multiplying it by 100, and the cos of 45 degrees (or pi/4 radians) is 0.7071067, and so the expected value to print out is 70.7106.

SIN and COS functions take the arguments in radians.  You use the correct formula to convert the input values from degrees to radians, and it's giving you the correct results for those converted values.

I'm curious how you could do the right conversion, and not realize that you did the right thing and got the right answer.  Did you take this code from somewhere else?